# Why don't I need to escape a character class in sed but I need to escape the rest?

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression

I am confused with sed.
I had a file with the following contents:

```
[ 2014/02/10 14:45:15 | INFO   ] Saving data for customer: 273667  
[ 2014/02/10 14:45:15 | INFO   ] Saving data for customer: 273687  
[ 2014/02/10 14:45:15 | INFO   ] Saving data for customer: 272667  
[ 2014/02/10 14:45:15 | INFO   ] Saving data for customer: 373667  
[ 2014/02/10 14:45:15 | INFO   ] Saving data for customer: 573667  
[ 2014/02/10 14:45:15 | INFO   ] Saving data for customer: 263667
```

I wanted to remove everything except the customer id. So I run the following:

```
$ sed 's/^.*:\s\(\[0-9\]\{6\}\)/\1/g' customers.txt > customers2.txt
```

This did not do absolutely anything.
After thinking about it (and a lot of frustration) I tried to remove the escapes from the `[]`. So I run the following:

```
$ sed 's/^.*:\s\([0-9]\{6\}\)/\1/g' customers.txt > customers2.txt
```

This worked.
But now I can not really undestand how sed works. Why do I need to escape `(` for grouping and `{` for range but not `[` for the character class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, because `[ ]` is part of the basic regular expression syntax while capture groups and `{}` are not. Escaping `[]` means you want to match a literal bracket, not a class.

As an aside, if what you want is to print the last field in a file, `awk` is much easier:

```
awk '{print $NF}' customers.txt > customers2.txt
```

In your particular case, you could also use `cut`:

```
cut -d':' -f 4 customers.txt > customers2.txt
```

and you can *always* use Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/.*:\s*//' customers.txt
```

Comment: Is this related to POSIX or NFA/DFA?

Comment: @Jim this is related to BRE, basic regular expressions which are defined in the [Single Unix Specification Version 2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/re.html#tag_007_003).

Answer (score 3):

For historical reasons. In the [first version of Unix](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/1/ed), only the characters `\[.*^$` had a special meaning in regular expressions. When newer features were added (option `\?`, repeat at least once `\+`, repeat count `\{…\}`, groups `\(…\)`, alternation `\|`), these could not make the characters `({|` special because it would have broken compatibility with existing scripts that used these characters literally. So [basic regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) and tools that build on them used backslash+character combinations that were not in use at the time.

Extended regular expressions broke compatibility in the interest of a consistent syntax.